# How to detect a function pointer type?

Tags: c#, function-pointers

Is there a way to detect the function pointer type for a field?

The C# 9 compiler accepts the following code:

```
unsafe class Foo
{   
    public delegate*<string, int> functionPointer = &GetLength;

    static int GetLength(string s) => s.Length;
}
```

What I've discovered so far using the reflection:

- the field type is `IntPtr`
- no custom attributes are applied to the field
- no custom modifiers are applied to the field